# Haskel Currying merging functions

Tags: haskell

Quick question I'm unable to understand how and why the following type definition gets formulated

```
:t const
const :: a -> b -> a

:t id
id :: a -> a

:t (const id)
(const id) :: b -> a -> a
```

Doesn't the following actually resolve too `a -> a -> b -> a` where  `a -> a` is feed inside of `a -> b -> a` AKA `(const(id _))`

anyone mind explaining how this is actually being transformed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const :: a -> b -> a
id :: c -> c
```

const before applied with id

```
const :: (c->c) -> b -> (c->c)
```

const after applied id

```
const id :: b -> (c -> c)
const id :: b -> c -> c
```

No matter what you apply to `const id` you get `c -> c`

Answer (score 2):

`const x :: b -> ??`, where `??` is the type of `x`. In this case, `x` is the function `id`, which has type `a -> a`. Thus, `const id :: b -> (a -> a)`, and you can drop the parentheses because `->` is right-associative.